# Calcular diferencia de fechas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de calcular la diferencia entre dos fechas, una que obtengo por entrada de pantalla y otra es el día actual que uno esta, pero no logro hacer que me haga el calculo

```
var FechaNacimiento = $("#txtFECHA_NACIMIENTO").val();  //este campo llega así ej: dd/mm/aaaa

var fechaFin = new Date()

fechaActual = fechaFin.getDate() + "/" + ((fechaFin.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' + (fechaFin.getMonth() + 1) : (d.getMonth() + 1)) + "/" + fechaFin.getFullYear();  //este es la fecha actual formateada a dd/mm/aaaa

var diff = Math.abs(fechaActual - FechaNacimiento);  //esta sentencia me llega NaN

diferenciaDias = Math.round(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));  //esta tambien llega NaN
```

porfavor ayudenme a resolver porque llega NaN, puede ser el formato de la fecha, pero he intentado de todas formas formatear las fecha a el ingles u otras y no resulta, y el moment.js no sirve

Comment: Diferencia de las fechas en que, dias?,minutos?,segundos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas trabajar directamente sobre objetos de fechas, obtenidos con `new Date()`, el cálculo que estás haciendo con `fechaActual` no es necesario (ni tiene sentido).

```js
var FechaNacimiento = $("#txtFECHA_NACIMIENTO").val();
// Crear objeto de fecha inicial con el valor del input
var fechaIni = new Date(FechaNacimiento);
// Crear objeto de fecha final (actual)
var fechaFin = new Date();

// Calcular diferencia en milisegundos
var diff = fechaFin - fechaIni;
console.log(diff);

// Calcular días
diferenciaDias = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
console.log(diferenciaDias);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="txtFECHA_NACIMIENTO" value="1995-09-13">
```

Si el formato necesariamente debe ser dd-mm-aaaa

```js
var FechaNacimiento = $("#txtFECHA_NACIMIENTO").val();
// Primero creamos un array, separando valores
var a1 = FechaNacimiento.split('-'); // [15, 03, 2020]
// Luego invertimos el orden
var a2 = a1.reverse(); // [2020, 03, 15]
// Crear cadena aaaa-mm-dd
var cadena = a2.join('-');

// Crear objeto de fecha
var fechaIni = new Date(cadena);
// Crear objeto de fecha final (actual)
var fechaFin = new Date();

// Calcular diferencia en milisegundos
var diff = fechaFin - fechaIni;
console.log(diff);

// Calcular días
diferenciaDias = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
console.log(diferenciaDias);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtFECHA_NACIMIENTO" value="15-03-2020">
```

Todos esos pasos se pueden simplificar, pero los dejé uno por uno para entender cómo se hace cada cosa.

Comment: @JackNavaRow, no entiendo, la operación se hace directamente con dos objetos tipo `Date`, ¿cuál sería la diferencia? Prueba el script poniendo la fecha de nacimiento en `2020-03-28`, en todo caso, para mayor certeza convendría usar `floor` en vez de `round`.

Comment: la fecha en javascript al mes tienes que restarle un antes de hacer la operacion

Comment: @JackNavaRow, NO, porque ambos son objetos `Date`, si lo hago con uno, también debería hacerlo con el otro y... ¿qué caso tiene?

Comment: @triby realicé tu forma de realizar y si me funcionó, lo unico que hay que añadirle es al calculo restarle 1 ya que debe ser por los años bisiestos estos le suman un dia al calculo y debe ser exacto, pero en general el codigo funciona y te lo agradesco mucho

Comment: @Triby estas comparando con fecha 13-08-95

Comment: @ClaudioAndresChacana, no es necesario restar 1, acabo de editar la respuesta, cambiando `round` a `floor` para que se haga el cálculo sobre 'días completos'.

Comment: ¿@JackNavaRow, revisaste que `fechaFin.getMonth()` devuelve 3? Estamos en abril. Pero no me creas, mejor lee la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getMonth)

Answer (score 0):

diff es igual a Nan porque estas intentando restar dos strings y no dos variables del tipo Date. Para realizar esa operacion que deseas necesitas realizarlo entre dos tipos Date y no entre String. Te dejo una posible solucion:

```
let fechaNacimiento = $("#txtFECHA_NACIMIENTO").val();  //este campo tiene que llegar en el formato aaaa/mm/dd
let fechaFin = new Date(fechaNacimiento);
let fechaActual = new Date();
let diff  = fechaActual - fechaFin;
let diferenciaDias = Math.round(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); //Diferencia en dias
```

Comment: Estimado, probé como me decias pero arroja invalid date y obiamente despues arroja NaN, el punto es el calculo, ese calculo no esta aceptando el formato de la fecha creo...

Comment: fijate que fechaNacimiento debe tener el formato aaaa/mm/dd y no  dd/mm/aaaa como estas utilizando en el codigo que publicaste

Comment: Ahi realice un cambio en el codigo, la variable se llamaba fechaNacimiento y no FechaNacimiento. Ahora tiene que andar, acuerdate que fechaNacimiento  debe recibir un string en el formato aaaa/mm/dd