# calcular días entre dos fechas

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas tardes comunidad espero me puedan ayudar
quiero calcular la cantidad de dias entre dos fechas pero
no me genera la cantidad mi código es el siguiente

los datos de las fechas los traigo de una base de datos

```
<label>Fecha de inicio</label>
<input type="text" id="timeStart" class="form-control" 
oninput="calculardiasDiscount()" value="<?= $FechadeIngreso ?>">


<label>Fecha fin</label>
<input type="text" id="timeEnd" class="form-control"
 oninput="calculardiasDiscount()"value="<?= $fecha_actual ?>" >
<label>Días</label>
<input class="form-control" id="daysDiscount">

<script>
function calculardiasDiscount() {
        var timeStart = new Date(document.getElementById("timeStart").value);
        var timeEnd = new Date(document.getElementById("timeEnd").value);
        var actualDate = new Date();
        if (timeEnd > timeStart)
        {
            var diff = timeEnd.getTime() - timeStart.getTime();
            document.getElementById("daysDiscount").value = Math.round(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        }
        else if (timeEnd != null && timeEnd < timeStart) {
            alert("La fecha final de la promoción debe ser mayor a la fecha inicial");
            document.getElementById("daysDiscount").value = 0;
        }
    }
</script>
```

[ejemplo 1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22073/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-la-diferencia-de-d%C3%ADas-entre-dos-fechas-en-javascript)
[ejemplo 2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/350345/calcular-diferencia-de-fechas)

Comment: No entiendo. Si ya encontraste la respuesta en esas 2 preguntas, por qué haces una pregunta nueva?

Comment: por que no gener la cantidad de dias

Comment: No es que haya repetido la misma pregunta, si no que tiene problemas para mostrar los datos

Comment: Hola! Disculpa, por qué dices que no funciona? COn qué datos probaste? Qué resultado obtienes y qué debería salir? Qué errores obtienes? Por favor, edita la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ejecutar la funcion utilizando `onload` en la etiqueta `<body>` asi:

```html
<body  onload="calculardiasDiscount()">
                    <label>Fecha de inicio</label>
<input type="text" id="timeStart" class="form-control" 
oninput="calculardiasDiscount()" value="12/08/2022">


<label>Fecha fin</label>
<input type="text" id="timeEnd" class="form-control"
 oninput="calculardiasDiscount()"value="12/19/2022" >
<label>Días</label>
<input class="form-control" id="daysDiscount">

<script onload="calculardiasDiscount()">
function calculardiasDiscount() {
        var timeStart = new Date(document.getElementById("timeStart").value);
        var timeEnd = new Date(document.getElementById("timeEnd").value);
        var actualDate = new Date();
        if (timeEnd > timeStart)
        {
            var diff = timeEnd.getTime() - timeStart.getTime();
            document.getElementById("daysDiscount").value = Math.round(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        }
        else if (timeEnd != null && timeEnd < timeStart) {
            alert("La fecha final de la promoción debe ser mayor a la fecha inicial");
            document.getElementById("daysDiscount").value = 0;
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: porque `12/19/2022`? creo que los campos deben ser de tipo `date` para que los datos sean válidos.

Comment: No necesariamente, el OP tiene datos originados del lado del servidor, las fechas que puse solo son un ejemplo.

Comment: Pues si los datos del servidor son de tipo date, no habría problema en mostrar los datos en un campo de tipo date.

Comment: No hay ningun problema, pero no es necesario

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ejecutar la función con el evento [**`onchange`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp), es decir, cuando ocurra un cambio en tu input, se ejecuta la función y se mostrará la diferencia entre las fechas:

```js
function calculardiasDiscount() {
  var timeStart = new Date(document.getElementById("timeStart").value);
  var timeEnd = new Date(document.getElementById("timeEnd").value);
  var actualDate = new Date();

  if (timeEnd > timeStart) {
    var diff = timeEnd.getTime() - timeStart.getTime();
    document.getElementById("daysDiscount").value = Math.round(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  }

  else if (timeEnd != null && timeEnd < timeStart) {
    alert("La fecha final de la promoción debe ser mayor a la fecha inicial");
    document.getElementById("daysDiscount").value = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Fecha de inicio</label>
<input type="date" id="timeStart" class="form-control" onchange="calculardiasDiscount()"><br><br>

<label>Fecha fin</label>
<input type="date" id="timeEnd" class="form-control" onchange="calculardiasDiscount()"><br><br>

<label>Días</label>
<input class="form-control" id="daysDiscount">
```